# What need to be setup for this reboot.sh to run first time after startup?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I have setup claymore miner in Xubuntu 16.4.3 and this program runs a reboot.sh script if something goes wrong.
My problem is that the script does not execute the first time after a startup of the system.

I get these errors.

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start reboot.target: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status reboot.target' for details.
Failed to open /dev/initctl: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

If i restart claymore miner and he needs to run the reboot.sh second time the system will restart.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i did some more research and found out that the reboot function needed a sudo authentication at least once so to bypass that i used this command in the script reboot.sh

```
echo "password" | sudo -S shutdown -r now
```

I hope this will help someone else some day.